# How to add background blur overlay to image?

Tags: flutter, image-flutter

I want to have a background overlay blur on a image if it is rectangular. Like if the image sides are of brown color it should have brown blur background to support its sides. Likewise if it has grey sides it should have grey blur background.

[This is what i want to achieve](https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Screenshot-2023-03-26-at-10.21.10-PM.png)

[One more example](https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Screenshot-2023-03-26-at-10.28.01-PM.png)

Pls help...

Comment: palette_generator to find the background color and use it to create blur.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
ClipRect(
              child: BackdropFilter(
                filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10.0, sigmaY: 10.0),
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey.shade200.withOpacity(0.5)
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Blue Image',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: This only add grey blur to it, I want according to the image color.